# Magento 2 Currency Rates Cron not run automatically

Tags: magento2, cron, currency

In Magento 2.1.8 website . currency rates does not automatically(cron) not working.

You can also show my "Scheduled Import Settings" into Below image

[image]

Comment: Have you configured cron job?

Comment: Please check my answer it will help you.

Comment: check my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

After change the setting run:

> php bin/magento cache:flush

For automatic rate updation to work, you need to make sure that Cron settings on your server.

For more detail check : [Link](https://www.humcommerce.com/tutorial/setup-currency-rates-update-magento-2/)